# why is there no overflow flag set for binary subtraction?

Tags: binary, verilog, cpu, alu

I have basic binary math question. For example;

```
reg [31:0] a = 32'hFFFF_FFFF; 
reg [31:0] b = 32'hFFFF_FFFF; 
reg [31:0] c = 0;
```

I know c = a - b will result in zero and overflow flag will not be set.

My understanding is that ALU uses 2's complement of subtrahend (right side of operator) and adds it to minuend (left side of operator).

So 2s complement for value stored in reg b is 32'h1. Now, if I add this to reg a, I will get 32 zeros and a 1, which is overflow. Then why is not overflow flag set?

Even if I change width of reg c to 33, c[32] is not set to 1. I understand that when two equal numbers are subtracted, there is no overflow but I get an overflow when I do 2s complement math.

Let help me clear this confusion in my head. 
Thank you for your time.

Comment: From age ~5 you are taught that subtracting two the same numbers gives zero. If you get to a different result, using assumptions, calculations and conclusions you know you are doing something wrong!

Answer (score 1):

`a`, `b`, and `c` are all 32-bit unsigned variables, and you are performing 32-bit arithmetic. The LRM says the resulting width of an arithmetic operation is the width of its largest operand.  So the *overflow* or 33rd bit is truncated. That fact remains true even when extending `c` to 33 bits.

Answer (score 1):

you have to look at what two's complement is. So, in your example `a` and `b` are 32-bit vectors with all bits set to '1':

```
 a[31:0] = 32'hFFFF_FFFF;
```

two's complement of this is 32'h0000_0001; so, adding it to `b` will cause all set to `0` and overflow bit `33` truncated because the width of the operation is 32 bits.

Now, supposedly you have a 33 bit vector

```
a[32:0] = 33'hFFFF_FFFF;
```

the two's complement will be `33'h1_OOOO_OOO1`. So, if you add it to a 33-bit vector `33'hFFFF_FFFF`, you will still have all 33 bits equal to '0'. If you add more bits to `a`, more `1` be added to the msb side: `34'h3_0000_0001`, ...

And, if `c` is wider than operation context, it will always be 0-extended, for unsigned vars, otherwise sign-extended.

As a result, you will always end up in the situation when the overflow bit is outside of the operation width, and is truncated. This is guaranteed by LRM requirement of the operation width.

Comment: thank you for your reply. if I change my test case to have all 1s in a, set b[0] = 1 and increase width of c to 33 bits and do an add instead of subtract, then c has 33'h100000000. should not width of result be limited to 32 and sign extend to have 0 in c[33]? All my regs are stil unsigned. thank you for taking time to explain this to me.

Comment: You will need to set width to `a` and/or `b` to 33 bits as well. This way the result of the addition will be 33 bit-wide and the upper bit will be set to '1'. But it is **not** equivalent to subtraction and '0000_0001' is **not** a two's compliment of FFFF_FFFF.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear.  a[31:0] = '1, b[31:0] = 1 and result is stored in c[32:0], based on your explanation result value greater than 32 bits will be truncated even if c is 33 bits so i should see all zeros in c. but i see 33'h100000000. i am doing addition in this test case.

Comment: i guess left hand side of the expression sets the width of the whole expression. So, the width of the context in which rhs is evaluated is the max width of all operands,  including lhs, which is 33 in your case.